Can I list multiple User-agents for a same set of robots.txt rules?
Is it valid to list User-agents like this?
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Yeti
User-agent: DuckDuckBot
Allow: /
Disallow: /private/

Otherwise, do I have to set it separately for each User-agent?
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Disallow: /private/

User-agent: Yeti
Allow: /
Disallow: /private/

User-agent: DuckDuckBot
Allow: /
Disallow: /private/

I'm confused by chatgpt's inconsistent answers..

Your Robots.txt syntax is correct. However, it can be slightly improved.
Since Robots.txt primarily serves to DISALLOW access for certain bots on your site, the Allow part is unnecessary.
Also note that your wildcard directive tells all other bots NOT to crawl your site, which can reduce access to legitimate bots (like Adsense or Bing to name a few). I wouldn't recommend that setting.
Finally, as a matter of order, I would put first the blocking-specific directives, and at the last part, the bot-specific (and/or wildcard *) for all the rest.
Your final Robots.txt file could look like this (replace Bad-Bot with whatever bot you want to block):
User-agent: Bad-Bot
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Yeti
User-agent: DuckDuckBot
User-agent: *
Disallow: /private/


"replace Bad-Bot with whatever bot you want to block" - Though, of course, be aware that a truly bad bot will ignore robots.txt altogether.
